# Looking for a way to correct Hard Drive geometry. # of cylinders is not correct

Tags: hard-disk, fdisk, sfdisk

I have 2 hard drives that have become corrupted as in the # of cylinders is no longer correct.  Not sure how this is happening, but have same hard drive model that I have verified the correct # of cylinders.
Early versions of sfdisk use to have this option.
And fdisk  x  has the options to modify the geometry but the w (write) command doesn't save the changes.
Found a program (Disk Genius @ $99) that says it will do the job but would hope their is a open source option?
Internet searches make mention that Gparted can do it, but I have not found that option.
I have used dd to zero out the HD and fdisk to remove and make new partition tables.  Everything is still using the wrong cylinder data.
Have tried fdisk under Linux Mint, Ubuntu and MX

Answer (score 1):

If the hard drives are larger than 7.87 GiB (or about 8.4 GB or exactly 16 450 560 blocks), they are accessed using Logical Block Addressing (LBA). That means only the block number is meaningful, and any "disk geometry" is going to be irrelevant.

If you are seeing C/H/S values of 1023/254/63 or 1023/255/63, those are dummy filler values used in MBR partition tables. They mean only "the actual values are bigger than can be expressed using C/H/S geometry values in MS-DOS or in the MBR partition table", and are *not* indicative of actual number of cylinders, heads or sectors.

Both the MBR partition table and MS-DOS used a 10-bit wide field for the Cylinder value, so only values between 0..1023 will fit. For the Head value, there is 8 bits, but for the Sector value, only 6 bits. Also there is a convention that the Sector values start from 1, not 0, and an old MS-DOS bug that prevents the use of Head #255.

At the level of PATA/IDE hardware, it was possible to use C/H/S style addressing up to 65536/16/255, which would mean a disk size of just short of 128 GiB (or 136.9 GB, or 2^28 blocks). But these values could not be used in MS-DOS, nor could they be stored in a MBR partition table; and as disk sizes reached that level, the actual internal geometry of the disks was already more complex than that (e.g. outer cylinders would have more physical sectors than inner ones). So even during the last days of PATA, C/H/S addressing was already on its way to becoming just a fiction needed to satisfy legacy operating systems, nothing more.

For modern disks larger than 7.87 GiB, if MBR partitioning is used, the only meaningful fields for determining the position and size of the partition are the LBA# of the first absolute sector of the partition, and the number of sectors in a partition. Since both of them are 4-byte fields, they can be used to express partitions up to 2 TiB, or up to LBA block number 0xffff ffff in hexadecimal.

So **unless you are talking about 20+ years old disks and operating systems, you can most likely ignore the "disk geometry" as it is not used for anything and is probably not even real anyway.**

Comment: Thanks for your response, not sure I can totally agree.  The reason I say that. The HD's are 2 & 4 TB. Regardless of the OS I look at them with / format them with they no longer show as their correct size. They now show as 1 and  2.75 TB.  Under Linux with fdisk & under Windoz with various programs the disk geometry is showing up as far lower than the other HD that is working normally. 
The 1 TB should have 243201 Cy but is reporting 121604, 4TB should be 7660841 but is reporting 3830527.  Result is no OS will format past the # of cylinders being reported.

Comment: That seems like broken hardware to me... or possibly someone trying to sell disks from a manufacturer's Quality Assurance rejects pile, using a hacked firmware to make them seem good. The disks may have lost an actual read/write head and falling back to the configuration of a lower-capacity sister model that has a reduced number of heads. I don't think you can fix it with any "normal" software: you would need the manufacturer-specific diagnostic/factory setup tools, and the knowledge to use them.

Comment: telcoM, totally agree, reported C's is almost 1/2 what it should be.

Comment: telcoM, The 1 TB has been working ok since 2019. I just got the 4TB HD on Monday, it reported correctly and formatted properly.  Installed Ubuntu and upgrades on OLD hardware.  Multiple reboots and power cycle.  Tried to boot on 2 other older systems neither would boot.  Went back to the hardware I did the install on and the partition table (GPT) was their but missing all but 1 partition.
My gut feeling is that something that I am doing is trashing the MFG data.  Both HD's are well under warranty so the 1TB is on the way back. 
I wanted to try to figure out why this is happening, and a fix.

Comment: Lost my login, had to recover...
Neighbor had Disk Genius.  Reset the #Cyl to what was factory.  "Looked" OK in Windoz but not in Linux.  Linux still shows 1/2 the expected size.  Formatted under Win and now Win is showing 1/2 the size.  Returned the HD back through Amazon.
I would still like to know how this happened.
Almost like 1 head died?

Comment: That seems a plausible explanation, particularly if that line of disks also includes one that has 1/2 capacity of the model you had., and so the disk firmware would recognize both configurations as valid ones, depending on how many heads it can detect. At the factory, when a batch of smaller disk models are required, one or two heads and the associated platters could simply be omitted. If that is the case, then the right kind of fault in the read/write head circuit would cause the disk to detect the head as "not present" and cause the fw to conclude "oh, I must be the low-capacity model".

Comment: Affecting the disk's firmware and its internal configuration is supposed to be impossible (or at least really difficult) without the appropriate software (and sometimes even hardware) tools, so unless you are doing something really special like fiddling with the `hdparm` options labelled as **DANGEROUS**, I think these were just hardware failures. Situations like this are ripe for the [post hoc fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) , as we humans are pre-disposed to assume causation for apparently correlating pairs of events.